# GameplayKit's nextIntWithUpperBound() failing in playground

Tags: ios, swift, gameplay-kit

The below code works great in an iOS project, but fails in an iOS playground. Any idea why, other than "it's probably a bug"? Note: you need to open the playground debug area to see the message: "overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int), (Range), (Range), (Self.Index)"

```
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

let countries = ["france", "germany", "italy"]
let randomIndex = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(3)
let chosenCountry = countries[randomIndex].uppercaseString

print(chosenCountry)
```

Again, that same code works just fine in a regular iOS project. It looks like something is confused about `Int` and `UInt`, because if I typecast `randomIndex` as `Int` it works fine.

Comment: Very strange, `String(reflecting: randomIndex.dynamicType)` prints `Swift.UInt` – it's probably a bug :).

Comment: The Objective-C method is `- (NSUInteger)nextIntWithUpperBound:(NSUInteger)upperBound`, so this seems to be an inconsistency whether a `NSUInteger` return value is imported to Swift as `Int` or `UInt` – this also changed between Xcode releases if I remember correctly.

Comment: Possibly a bug on the Swift/Playground/Xcode side... be sure to [file it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).